# Using C# HTML agility pack to scrape the Image Source out of a particular table in a html page

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm trying to extract the image sources out of one table in a page, however my code is currently extracting all the image sources of the whole page, not just that one table. Any help on helping me to be able to extract the image source out of the first table in the html page would be greatly appreciated.

```
 var tables= html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[1]").ToList();

 foreach (var table in tables)
 {
     if (html.DocumentNode != null)
     {
         var images = html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img/@src");

         if (images.Any())
         {
             bodyList.AddRange(images.Select(t => t.OuterHtml + (i + 1).ToString()));
         }
     }                  
 }
```

Comment: try replacing `"//img/@src"` with `"..//img/@src"` - this limits the scope to just the images that matches the criteria, whereas not having the `..` takes all instances. also, you should reference `var images = table.SelectNodes("..//img/@src");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the table nodes first instead of the image ones and then select the images nodes

```
    var tables = html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table").ToList();
    List<string> bodyList = new List<string>();
    foreach (var table in tables)
    {
        if (html.DocumentNode != null)
        {
            var images = table.SelectNodes("//img/@src");

            if (images.Any())
            {
                bodyList.AddRange(images.Select(t => t.OuterHtml + (i + 1).ToString());
            }
        }                  
    }
```

This will extract the images out of all the tables in the html, to just extract from the first one

```
List<string> bodyList = new List<string>();
var table = html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table").FirstOrDefault();
If (table != null)
{
    bodyList.AddRange(table.SelectNodes("//img/@src").Select(t => t.OuterHtml + (i + 1).ToString());
}
```

Comment: Had a go with that thanks, still pulling every link in the page through

Comment: You are pulling every link because you are searching the entire html html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img/@src"); use the table instead